# Temporary deny outbound traffic in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to perform a simulation to see how the system would react when it's disconnected and reconnected back. If it's done locally I could easily disable my WIFI and enable it back. If I had done the same in AWS I'd get kicked out from my RDP / SSH session and it wouldn't be possible for me to reconnect back to the session to enable the network back.

Any other suggestion to achieve this?

Comment: Can you expand on what you're trying to achieve. There are a number of approaches but you should be cautious to take the right one for you.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the outbound rules on the security group associated to your instance. You can do this from either the console or the cli, with:

```
aws ec2 update-security-group-rule-descriptions-egress --group-id id --ip-permissions permissions
```

See the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/update-security-group-rule-descriptions-egress.html) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

Use an AWS lambda to enable and disable a security group which denies outbound traffic. You could just add a time.sleep(60) to wait a a minute between actions.